# Given System.Type T, Deserialize List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, generic-list

I have a number of classes that I want to serialize and de-serialize.  I am trying to create a function that, given a type ("User", "Administrator", "Article", etc) will de-serialize the file with the list of those items.  For example:

```
/* I want to be able to do this */
List<Article> allArticles = GetAllItems(typeof(Article));
```

I cannot figure out how to achieve the above, but I managed to get this working:

```
/* BAD: clumsy method - have to pass a (typeof(List<Article>)) 
    instead of typeof(Article)  */
List<Article> allArticles = (List<Article>)GetAllItems(typeof(List<Article>));

/* Then later in the code... */
public static IList GetAllItems(System.Type T)
{

    XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(T);

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(GetPathBasedOnType(T));
    IList items = (IList) deSerializer.Deserialize(tr);
    tr.Close();

    return items;
}
```

The problem is that I have to pass "ugly" `typeof(List<Article>)` instead of "pretty" `typeof(Article)`.

When I try this:

```
List<User> people = (List<User>)MasterContactLists.GetAllItems(typeof(User));

/* Followed by later in the code...*/
public static IList GetAllItems(System.Type T)
{
    XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(GetPathBasedOnType(T));
    IList items = (IList)deSerializer.Deserialize(tr);
    tr.Close();

    return items;
}
```

... I get an error

```
/*Error 3 
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
on this line: ... = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>)); */
```

Question:  how can I fix my `GetAllItems()` to be able to call the function like this and have it return a list:

```
List<Article> allArticles = GetAllItems(typeof(Article));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there... you need to declare a generic method:

```
public static IList<T> GetAllItems<T>()
{
    XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

    using(TextReader tr = new StreamReader(GetPathBasedOnType(typeof(T))))
    {
        IList<T> items = (IList<T>)deSerializer.Deserialize(tr);
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! And if I want to cache the items, I'd use...
    Cache["asset" + typeof(T).ToString()] = items;
...right?

Comment: Thanks, Thomas.  This is really helpful.  Though looks like changing the function declaration/prototype requires rewriting a ton of dependent code. Is there an easier way within the function with declaration GetAllItems(System.Type T) to instantiate a serializer of the **LIST** of those elements - like this: "new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));"?

Comment: It's possible, but quite ugly... you would have to use `new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(T))`.